# Nginx Rewrite to remove php filename

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

Hej

It is possible to write a Rewrite Rule in Nginx for Removing a filename?

I have it like this:
domain.tld/post.php?p=1
and want somthing like this:
domain.tld/?p=1

Is there a way for it? And if is, how?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely.

It's a fairly common practice to redirect all requests to your `index.php` file, and then for that to route the requests within your application logic - this way your PHP code can define your URL structures entirely.

If you wanted to do so, here's an example Nginx rewrite configuration you can use to rewrite all requests to index.php:

```
#
# Redirect all to index.php
#
RewriteEngine On

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/[^.]*|\.)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```